# ¿Cuáles son las diferencias entre Power Query, Power Pivot, Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerpivot, powerquery

Quiero hacer un aporte a la comunidad presentando estas herramientas gratuitas para el análisis de datos usando Microsoft y que lamentablemente son poco conocidas y/o exploradas por muchos aun y pueden ser muy útiles en nuestros trabajos para la automatización y creación de reportes, muy utilizadas hoy en día en **Inteligencia de Negocios** ya que permite analizar grandes volúmenes de datos en nuestro ya conocido Microsoft Excel y es mas intuitivo para aquellos que no se familiarizan con las "macros" VBA.

Esperemos que con el tiempo las etiquetas **powerquery**, **powerbi** y **powerpivot** se llenen de preguntas por el uso de los lenguajes **M** y **DAX**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Power Query** Es un [complemento](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?id=39379) desarrollado desde la versión de Excel 2010 y ahora por defecto en la versión 2016 como **Get & Transform**. Es parte de la propuesta de Microsoft para el desarrollo de ETL por sus siglas en inglés (Extract, Transform, Load) (Extraer, Transformar, Cargar) muy acorde con la coyuntura del análisis de grandes volúmenes de información para cualquier sector económico y social.

PQ Permite conectar Excel con múltiples fuentes de información y transformarlas intuitivamente en el **Editor de Consultas**. Allí se encuentran una cantidad considerable de herramientas para transformar nuestros datos, estos se almacenan paso a paso dándonos total control sobre el proceso de transformación.

[image]

Adicional nos presenta el [lenguaje](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/mt779182.aspx) **M** o **Power M** para los mas avanzados es la posibilidad de acceder línea a línea o paso a paso para editar la consulta y poder incorporar el resto de funciones que no se encuentran en el entorno básico del **editor de consultas**.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Source, "Items", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Items.1", "Items.2"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Items.1", type text}, {"Items.2", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Category"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Removed Columns",{{"Value", "Item"}})
in
    #"Renamed Columns"
```

**Power Pivot** Es otro [complemento](https://www.microsoft.com/es-es/download/details.aspx?) [como](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZCO3y27z8E) PQ desarrollado desde la versión 2010 incorporado nativamente desde la versión 2013. Acá podemos conectar múltiples fuentes de información o con la data ya transformada en Power Query. Gracias a su tecnología de memoria integrada permite almacenar millones de registros sin mayor problema contrario a nuestra limitada hoja de Excel.

Nos presenta las [funciones](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-co/library/gg413422.aspx) **DAX** que son desarrolladas para formular y extraer información de cubos de datos y nos permite crear complejas métricas e indicadores KPI (Key Performance Indicators).

Permite crear nuestros modelos de datos de manera relacional como ya conocemos en Access y posteriormente visualizarlos usando nuestras tradicionales tablas dinámicas y gráficos o de manera dinámica con **Power View** y **Power Maps**.

**PowerBI** es un [software](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/) gratuito para la creación de Dashboards o reportes dinámicos, donde también podremos encontrar el editor de consultas **Power Query** y las formulas **DAX**, con estas dos poderosas herramientas PowerBI nos permite analizar grandes volúmenes de información y la posibilidad de compartirlas en nuestra organización ya sea de manera local o online dependiendo el caso.

[image]

[Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/lZA_r5aVetU)

Comment: muy buena respuesta hermano, gracias por compartir :D

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias! He estado usando estas herramientas por años y recién comencé en esto de stackoverflow. Veo con tristeza que en la comunidad en inglés esto es mas activo y en la hispana ni siquiera estaban las etiquetas. Esto me motivo a la creación de este post ya que no podemos dejarnos tomar ventaja. Saludos! :D

Comment: ¡Esa es la actitud bro! Date una vuelta por la sala de chat https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol :D