# Repetir el valor campo de una consulta SQL

Tags: sql, excel

Estoy realizando una consulta en SQL y con la siguiente necesidad en la tabla consultada tengo el documento en dos momentos o estatus (1) cuando se origina y (2) cuando se "liga a otro proceso" el punto es que cuando genero la consulta solo los registros del momento 1 tienen descripción y la requiero también en el momento 2.

En mi consulta utilizo un `left join` para traer otros valores que dependen de los documentos relacionados con los recibos, sin embargo entiendo que por la lógica de la consulta no logro entender la lógica para poder repetir el valor de acuerdo a lo expuesto arriba.

```
Select  
T01."Transaction No_" AS "Transacción",  
T01."Entry No_" AS "Registro",  
T01."Entry Type" AS "TipoR",  
T01."Cust_ Ledger Entry No_" AS "Rcte",  
T01."Posting Date" AS "FechaR",  
T01."Document No_" AS "Docto",  
T01."Amount (LCY)" AS "Importe", 
T01."Customer No_" AS "CFacturado",  
T02."Name" AS "Nombre",  
T03."Description" AS "Descripción",  
T03."Bal_ Account No_" AS "Cta",  
T03."Bal_ Account Type" AS "TipoCta",  
T03."No_ Series" AS "Serie",  
T04."Posting Date" AS "FechaR",  
T04."Document No_" AS "Docto"  
 FROM  
 RTM1.dbo."BD$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry" "T01",  
 RTM1.dbo."BD$Customer" "T02",  
 RTM1.dbo."BD$Cust_ Ledger Entry" "T03"  
 Left Join  
 RTM1.dbo."BD$Cust_ Ledger Entry" "T04"  
 on  
 T03."Entry No_" = T04."Entry No_"  
 WHERE  
 "T01"."Customer No_" = "T02"."No_"  
 AND "T01"."Cust_ Ledger Entry No_" = "T03"."Entry No_"  
  AND T01."Posting Date"  BETWEEN date1 and date2 "
```

El espacio del círculo rojo es donde quiero que se repita la información en común tienen el tipo de documento (que no aparece aquí, el número de cliente y el número de documento:

[image: El espacio del circulo rojo es donde quiero que se repita la información en común tienen el tipo de documento (que no aparece aqui, el número de cliente y el número de documento]

Comment: Hola Ruben, bienvenido! Debes mostrar que has intentado y en que estás fallando, te invito a que revises [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Gracias, he ampliado el contexto de mi pregunta (espero haberlo hecho bien) agregando el código de mi consulta es una consulta desde Excel a través de vba se puede decir que la consulta funciona correctamente y me pregunto si es posible repetir el dato que menciono.

Comment: has probado a no hacer un left-join? lo digo porque las otras tablas las haces con un producto cartesiano y sus condiciones. Quizas quitando el left-join y añadiendo su condicion saques algo mas... (aunque luego tengas que filtrar a mayores por otros campos)

Comment: Necesitariamos mas informacion, como datos de ejemplo por ejemplo. Si descripcion viene de la tabla T3, que esperas mostrar? en los  casos que viene vacio, quiere decir que no hay valores ahi que cumplan esa condicion.

Answer (score 0):

Por la naturaleza del `left join` si no encuentra `T03.[Entry No_]` en el campo `T04.[Entry No_]` lo mostrará como vacío. Si esta conectando esta consulta con Excel, una opción es usar **Power Query** para ello. Es un [complemento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135299/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-diferencias-entre-power-query-power-pivot-power-bi) que le permitirá conectar Excel directamente con la consulta y dispondrá de toda una gama de herramientas para transformar sus datos.

para su caso puede organizar de manera ascendente por el campo `[Transacción]` y luego **rellenar hacia abajo** en el campo `[Descripción]` para eliminar espacios en blanco. Al final solo será dar **clic derecho** > **Actualizar** y tendrá siempre su reporte al día.

[image]