# Formula para extraer mas de un dato de un mismo cliente

Tags: excel

formula para recopilar mas de un dato de un mismo cliente, y este sea colocado en el primer nombre encontrado del cliente, (cabe mencionar que la base esta acomodada por orden alfabetico)la base se encuentra de la siguiente manera:

```
ID                     nombre              facturas
A02032018000    DISTRIBUIDORA DE CARNES       3095
A02032018000    DISTRIBUIDORA DE CARNES       3803
A28022018M00    DISTRIBUIDORA DE CARNES       1520
```

y el proceso que requiero es lo siguiente:

```
ID                     nombre              facturas   Formula / recopilacion
A02032018000    DISTRIBUIDORA DE CARNES       3095    3095, 3803, 1520
A02032018000    DISTRIBUIDORA DE CARNES       3803
A28022018M00    DISTRIBUIDORA DE CARNES       1520
```

ocupo que quede en una celda queden todas las facturas del mismo cliente en vez de seleccionar la celda copiar y pegar en la misma celda, quiero que todo quede en una sola.

Comment: Solo Con fórmulas no podrás hacer lo que quieres, que yo sepa. Me temo que necesitarás VBA. Otra opción sería usar tablas dinámicas, y así agrupar tus datos por ID y NOMBRE y tener rápidamente una lista de las facturas asociadas.

Comment: de casualidad tendrá el formato de la macro? o como puedo elaborarla

Comment: Tienes que programarla en VBA. Tendrás que aprender VBA, y cuando te vaya surgiendo alguna duda concreta del código, entonces puedes preguntar aquí. Otra opción sería utilizar el grabador de macros, que ya te sirve como introducción un poco a lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: @ElierSánchezE-Infantes Sí es posible extraer más de un dato usando fórmulas. Lamentablemente la pregunta no incluye una descripción de lo buscado/investigado ni de lo intentado.

Comment: Esta pregunta está marcada como duplicado de otra que fue eliminada. Debería quitarse el duplicado.

Comment: gracias @Rubén, bien visto

Answer (score 1):

Existen dos formas para solucionar esto si tiene Excel 2016 puede usar la formula `UNIRCADENAS`

`{=UNIRCADENAS(", ",1,SI($B$2:$B$4=E2,$C$2:$C$4,""))}`

Para activar la formula como arreglo utilice <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Otra opción es usar **Power Query**, acá un [link](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135299/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-diferencias-entre-power-query-power-pivot-power-bi) donde hago una breve descripción de las nuevas herramientas de microsoft para inteligencia de negocios.

En el editor de consultas siga estos pasos para agrupar sus datos:

[image]

Acá un [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iolvOPdS4SY) detallado que hice hace un tiempo sobre este tema en particular.