# macro, unir hojas de diferentes libros d excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Soy investigador de macros en excel, hasta ahora me considero un principiante en esta labor, necesito su ayuda para poder resolver un problema.

Necesito unir varios archivos de excel en uno solo, esto lo he podido lograr con una macro como:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'NOTA: CAMBIA C:\Users\f13619\Desktop\BBBBBB POR LA RUTA QUE TENGAS TUS ARCHIVOS

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\f13619\Desktop\BBBBBB")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files
For Each everyObj In filesObj
Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
'change "A2" with cell reference of start point for every files here
'for example "B3:IV" to merge all files start from columns B and rows 3
'If you're files using more than IV column, change it to the latest column
'Also change "A" column on "A65536" to the same column as start point
Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
'Do not change the following column. It's not the same column as above
Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

pero quisiera saber que debo cambiar en este código porque solo une las primeras hojas y lo que necesito es unir todas las hojas 1 en una sola hoja 1, todas las hojas 2 en una sola hoja 2.... y así sucesivamente, debo mencionar que todas las hojas tienen la misma estructura, de antemano, gracias por su apoyo espero haberme expresado bien.

Gracias

Comment: Esencialmente necesitas seleccionar el contenido de cada hoja uno y ponerlo en la hoja uno del workbook destino, cuidando de no traslapar los datos

Comment: si, exactamente necesito que cada hoja del archivo destino tenga el contenido de la union de las hojas respectivas de los archivos origen.

Comment: Tendrás que ir creando bucles para ir seleccionando cada Hoja1 y pegar los contenidos en una única Hoja1. Y así con todas las hojas, hasta que obtengas tu Libro Excel definitivo con todos los datos.

Comment: Gracias, si tengo clara la idea de que es lo que tengo que hacer lo que no se es como hacerlo, si tuvieses algún código que pudiese usar de base te lo agradecería.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le aconsejaría que para unir hojas en excel usara [Power Query](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/135299/cu%C3%A1les-son-las-diferencias-entre-power-query-power-pivot-power-bi) en lugar de `VBA` con unos pocos clics tiene los resultados esperados y es mas estable y rápido que una macro.

[image]

Para la macro sería:

```
Sub simpleXlsMerger()
Dim bookList As Workbook
Dim mergeObj As Object, dirObj As Object, filesObj As Object, everyObj As Object
Dim i, WS_Count, WS_Count2 As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set mergeObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'NOTA: CAMBIA C:\Users\f13619\Desktop\BBBBBB POR LA RUTA QUE TENGAS TUS ARCHIVOS

Set dirObj = mergeObj.Getfolder("C:\Users\f13619\Desktop\BBBBBB")
Set filesObj = dirObj.Files

Workbooks.Add 'crea archivo nuevo para almacenar hojas unidas
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="master.xlsx" 'guarda archivo en documentos

For Each everyObj In filesObj
    Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(everyObj)
    WS_Count = bookList.Worksheets.Count 'cuenta cuantas hojas hay en el libro
    For i = 1 To WS_Count 'En esta linea itera por cada hoja del libro
        bookList.Worksheets(i).Activate 'hoja a unir
        Range("A2:IV" & Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
        Workbooks("master.xlsx").Worksheets(i).Activate
        Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        WS_Count2 = Workbooks("master.xlsx").Worksheets.Count 'cuenta cuantas hojas hay en master
        If WS_Count2 < WS_Count Then
            Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet 'adiciona nueva hoja
        End If
    Next i
    bookList.Close
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Si, solo que por ahora no puedo tener accesos suficientes para trabajar con power query, la empresa no lo permite por eso necesito hacer la macro

Comment: Puede iterar por especificas hojas de un libro con esta linea: `Worksheets(i).Select` siendo `i` el numero de hoja según el orden que tenga en el libro sin importar sus nombres.

Comment: esta linea donde la puedo ubicar porque no corre la macro

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, no la puedo probar pero en teoria debe funcionar.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, he probado con la macro que enviaste pero me sigue copiando solo las primeras hojas de cada libro pero no copia más, intente cambiar el For i = 1 To WS_Count hasta después de abrir el libro pero me da error

Comment: Listo hice unas pruebas y funciona, adapte la macro para que cree un libro nuevo y allí una según la hoja. Lo único es que no pone encabezados.

Comment: Disculpa que inomode nuevamente con el mismo tema, abri un nuevo excel y pegue la macro en un nuevo modulo, pero al ejecutarlo me sale "subindice fuera del intervalo" ademas me crea un libro llamado master pero solo copia los datos de la primera hoja del primer archivo nada más, no se si será por la versión de excel yo trabajo con excel 2013. Gracias

Comment: Puede ejecutarla paso a paso con `F8` con pocos archivos y decirme que linea genera el error. Es posible uno de los archivos este diferente a la gran mayoría. La idea es que esta macro cree un archivo nuevo y allí agrupe cada hoja de los archivos en la carpeta.

Comment: Lo revise en detalle, algo curioso porque paso a paso no me generó problemas, pero ya se arregló. Muchas gracias por tu aporte.